# Thunderbird: new email sound notification not working

Tags: thunderbird

Thunderbird does not play the sound file when new message arrives, even though I have this set up correctly:

[image]

The sound file playes OK when I press the <kbd>Play</kbd> button, but when new message arrives nothing happens.

The message preview text also is not displayed when new message arrives, even though I have this set up too.

What could be the problem? How can  I make the sound play?